# How should I find the correlation between multiple variables in R? "Standard deviation is 0" error

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I'm extremely new to R and not good with statistics (not a good combination, I know). I have a dataset (genes) with genes found in different species. It looks something like this:

```
genes   sp1    sp2    sp3    sp4    sp5
genea   100    100    100    100    100
geneb     0     0     8.333   0     11.11
genec   100    11.11  16.6    0     16.6
```

The numbers correspond to the percentage of presence of the gene to each species. I want to know the correlation of the presence/absence of the genes between one another using this data. I tried using the cor() and corrplot to visualize. And corr_cross()to show the significant correlations:

```
genes<- t(genes) #just to transpose the rowxcolumn

corr_cross(genes,  # to show top 10 couples of variables (by correlation coefficient)
           max_pvalue = 0.05, # display only significant correlations (at 5% level)
           top = 10 
)

genes <- cor(genes)
corrplot(genes, 
         type = "lower", 
         order = "AOE", 
         tl.srt = 45, 
         col = brewer.pal(n = 8, name = "RdYlGn"), 
         bg = "lightblue",
         title = "Association of virulence factors",
         mar=c(0,0,1,0))
dev.off()
```

When I do this, I get NA values and a warning message that says that the standard deviation is zero. I know that this is because of some genes that are present in all strains of all species, therefore having a similar data of "100" across all species.

How can I revise my code to show associations between all genes even with similar values for some columns? Or should I change my statistical method?

Comment: you have to exclude the rows with zero standard deviation

Comment: But I also want to know the correlation of those values with other values?

Comment: it is not possible to know a correlation of one variable with a constant

Comment: Correlation can be thought of, VERY roughly, as "how closely related are the changes in X to the changes in Y". So if either X or Y never changes, you can't have a correlation